# Excel formula to Sum the last 30 rows of a cell range that has new rows added daily?

Tags: excel, indexing, max, row

I have a column that has data added everyday, but I only ever need to pull the last 30, to effectively give me a "Rolling 30 Day" view of the metric. How do I pull just the most recent (lowest in the column) 30 entries?

In SQL it's something a simple as "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30", but this I need something probably more manual per row for Excel, semantically like:

"=SUM(The last row in A:A) + (The last row in A:A -1) + (The last row in A:A -2)...through to the last row - 30)"

I guess an easier question is how to get a specific row from a column, using the most recent entry / highest row count number and subtracting some value from it, and I can dupe that 30 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will do it

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(99^99,A:A,1)-29):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(99^99,A:A,1)))
```

The Match with the impossibly high number will identify the last row and return that row's number. Subtract 29 from that to get the row number for the start of your 30 day time range and then use these two Match results in two Index formulas. Combine the Index functions with the range operator `:` and sum the whole thing.

You can use the "Evaluate Formula" command on the Formulas ribbon to see how the formula resolves into the desired range.

[image]